# After effects scripting button element onclick

Tags: javascript, scripting, onclick, after-effects

I wrote some code for a simple button - [`onclick`]. I want to know what is the right way or why this is not working in the way that I have written it ??

```
function main(thisObj) {
    function windowCreate(thisObj) {

        var mainWindow = (thisObj instanceof Panel) ? thisObj : new 
        Window("palette", "", [100, 100, 300, 280]);//

        var groupOne = mainWindow.add ("group", [0,0,310,210], "Positions");
        groupOne.orientation = "row";

        Button1 = groupOne.add("button",[10,10,100,40],"P_0:0");


        return mainWindow;
    }

    var Window1 = windowCreate (thisObj);
    if ((Window1 != null) && (Window1 instanceof Window)) {
        Window1.center();
        Window1.show();
        }
    }
    main(this);
        }
    Button1.onclick = Click();

    function Click(){
            alert("Button 1 clicked");
        }
```

In this code, if I run the script in after effects the button click executes automatically the first time and then it does nothing when I click it. Why isn't  this working?

Comment: I dont know about after effects scripting but since its javascript i think the mistake is that when you assign the Click() function you use parantheses so its like calling the function instead of assigning it. You should do that `Button1.onClick = Click;`  possibly

Comment: then What if I want to add a button.onclick function that must take some parameters ? Like button1.onClick = Click(x,y,) this .

Comment: In any case,  first the parameters should be declared in the function declaration e.x. `function Click(parameters...)` . Now For e.x. in a browser environment you can declare as parameter the event object as: `function Click(event)` and from the event you can access x,y coordinates of the mouse, the element that was clicked e.t.c. Now in your case i dont know what you need to do exactly so i cannot make a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function windowCreate() {
    mainWindow.groupOne = mainWindow.add ("group", [0,0,310,210], "Positions");
    mainWindow.groupOne.orientation = "row";

    mainWindow.Button1 = mainWindow.groupOne.add("button",[10,10,100,40],"P_0:0");
    mainWindow.Button1.onClick = function() { Click(); };
    return mainWindow;
}


function Click(){
    alert("Button 1 clicked");
}

var mainWindow = new Window("palette", "", [100, 100, 300, 280]);//
var Window1 = windowCreate();
if ((Window1 != null) && (Window1 instanceof Window)) {
Window1.center();
Window1.show();
}
```

I'm using CC 2014.

Comment: thank you. It seem we have to call function in  button.onClick() = function(){
    "here"  someFunction();
}